# How to use Graalvm's Truffle framework with Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, graalvm, polyglot

The [Graalvm jdk](https://www.graalvm.org/) uses the [Truffle framework](https://github.com/oracle/graal/tree/master/truffle) to call functions and receive objects from other languages, such as R, Python, Ruby and Javascript. How can I use it from Groovy? Can I call it's APIs using Groovy code? Or do I have to call the Truffle APIs using Java code and then call this Java code from Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not interested in Truffle API, which is API for the development of new Truffle based languages, but in Graal SDK: API for embedding Truffle languages into Java applications. I guess you can use that API from Groovy like you would use any other Java API.

Some resources:

https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/embed/

https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/index.html?org/graalvm/polyglot/Context.html

TL;DR example in Java:

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.proxy.*;

public class HelloPolyglot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Java!");
        try (Context context = Context.create()) {
            context.eval("js", "print('Hello JavaScript!');");
        }
    }
}
```